# Apache Camel : Custom Redelivery Policy

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a route that calls an external rest service. I have configured my error handler as shown below.

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("jms:dlc").maximumRedeliveries(3));
```

What i want to do:

- If connection to external api fails, i want to retry 3 times and then send to deadLetterChannel
- If api call is fine, i want to check the status code, log the response and then send the message to deadLetterChannel.

For that i set **throwExceptionOnFailure** to false.

In my route i have a bean as the last endpoint. This bean receives the response from the external end point and checks for the status.

```
void process(Exchange exchange){
  //check http status code
  //if not success
  exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP,true);
  //sendToDeadLetterQueue;
  }
```

My problem is that redelivery happens even when i am able to connect to API. I expect the redelivery to happen on error. But i am handling the response and also setting the exchange to stop.

Can i stop the redelivery from my bean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onException as follows:

```
<onException>
   <exception>SomeException</exception>
   <handled><constant>true</constant></handled>
   <process ref="failureResponse"/>
</onException
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onException tag handled as true

Java DSL

`onException(ExceptionClass).handled(true)
  .to(deadLetterChannel);`

Spring DSL :

```html
<onException>
<exception>SomeException</exception>
   <handled><constant>true</constant></handled>
   <to uri=deadLetterChannel/>
</onException>
```

For More Clarification click [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/html/Apache_Camel_Development_Guide/BasicPrinciples-ExceptionHandling.html)